# how to catch errors in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

Im using the following in htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /core/php/error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /core/php/error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /core/php/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /core/php/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /core/php/error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /core/php/error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /core/php/error.php
```

error.php looks like this:

```
switch($_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]){
        case 400:
        xxxxxxxxx relevant code here
        break;
        case 403:
        xxxxx code here
        break;
        ...
```

I want to know EXACTLY what are the resources that are giving the 404 errors (put them in an array like this:

```
$array[err01][image.jpg]
      [err02][file.html]
```

and also want to know the exact url that caused a 403 error, like this:

```
$array[referer][here goes the referer, if it exists]
      [403 error route][user tried to access: public/admin/core/php]
```

can it be done? and if so, HOW?!!!
Wasted a whole day on this and still nothing! (what a noob!)

Comment: there should be another $_SERVER value that has the original request's URL, the one that triggered the error. do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` and dig through the output. I can't remember offhand what its name is, but it'll be "HTTP_ORIGINAL_REQUEST" or something similar.

Comment: thank you, that worked, the $_SERVER value was REQUEST_URI

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_URI is the $_SERVER value that did it